# Where is stored the messages results from T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know if SQL Server store all messages related to T-SQL in a system table or in other object from Database Engine.

Because, I don't know if this is a response of engine or some other stuff.

[image]

[image]

Now, I did this to capture transactions

[image]

And I need to do that for each transaction that I want to "control" (number of register inserted, deleted or updated)

Comment: U mean for number of rows affected ?

Comment: No, SQL Server does not keep track of these transient output messages anywhere...

Comment: I suspect you might get a better answer if you explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, I would like to catch the transaction that I execute without alter my script. I was working with a Stored procedure or Trigger to do that but I need to configure my script to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The message you're seeing is *not* generated by SQL Server itself; it just returns "12".

SQL Server *Management Studio* generates the complete message; it's a .NET application so it's probably coming from a .resx file which gets compiled into the application package. With a decompiler or DLL analyzer you might be able to find it among the other messages.

Comment: What about of response from sqlcmd? because if you execute a script in a sqlcmd, console shows a similar response.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot, the highlight message that you are seeing is called `DONE_IN_PROC messages` and that is from the client - in your case SSMS.

You can suppress it using [`set nocount on`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

> setting SET NOCOUNT to ON can provide a significant performance boost, because network traffic is greatly reduced.

The error messages (system-defined and user-defined messages) that are stored in sql server can be queried using [sys.messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/messages-for-errors-catalog-views-sys-messages?view=sql-server-2017)